# autocmd filetype nnoremap is not working

Tags: autocmd, filetype

I'm trying to create a mapping based on the file type. (as explained in this chapter https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.htm)

```
:autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c I//<esc>
```

To test this mapping, I open a new buffer (through `:vsplit`) containing a javascript file but the mapping does not work at all and I don't understand why.

When I hit `,` and `c` simultaneously I expect vim to add `//` in the left of my line.

The relevant settings:

> ```
> let mapleader=,
> set ft? --> filetype=javascript
> ```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This is what I get when I hit `:nmap`

```
n  ,c          *@I//<Esc>
n  %             <Plug>(MatchitNormalForward)
n  (             [
n  )             ]
n  ,ts         * :PHPUnitSwitchFile<CR>
n  ,tf         * :PHPUnitRunCurrentFile<CR>
n  ,ta         * :PHPUnitRunAll<CR>
n  ,da         * :call PhpDocAll()<CR>
n  ,cog        * :call PhpCreateGetters()<CR>
n  ,sg         * :call PhpCreateSettersAndGetters()<CR>
n  ,du         * :call PhpDetectUnusedUseStatements()<CR>
n  ,np         * :call PhpCreateProperty()<CR>
n  ,ep         * :call PhpExtractClassProperty()<CR>
n  ,rm         * :call PhpRenameMethod()<CR>
n  ,eu         * :call PhpExtractUse()<CR>
n  ,rcv        * :call PhpRenameClassVariable()<CR>
n  ,rlv        * :call PhpRenameLocalVariable()<CR>
n  ,r            <Plug>(FerretAcks)
n  ,l            <Plug>(FerretLack)
n  ,sv         * :source $MYVIMRC<CR>
n  ,ev         * :vsplit $MYVIMRC<CR>G
n  ,bs           :CtrlPMRU<CR>
n  ,bm           :CtrlPMixed<CR>
n  ,bb           :CtrlPBuffer<CR>
n  ,p            :CtrlP<CR>
n  ,A          * :exec "Rg ".expand("<cword>")<CR>
n  ,a          * :Rg<Space>
n  ,f            :NERDTreeFind<CR>
n  ,t            :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
n  ,s          * :%s/\<<C-R><C-W>\>/
n  <p          & :<C-U>call <SNR>52_putline(v:count1 . ']p', 'Below')<CR><']
n  <P          & :<C-U>call <SNR>52_putline(v:count1 . '[p', 'Above')<CR><']
n  <leader-o>  * :CtrlPTag<CR>
n  =p          & :<C-U>call <SNR>52_putline(v:count1 . ']p', 'Below')<CR>=']
n  =P          & :<C-U>call <SNR>52_putline(v:count1 . '[p', 'Above')<CR>=']
n  =op         * <Nop>
n  =o            <SNR>52_legacy_option_map(nr2char(getchar()))
n  >p          & :<C-U>call <SNR>52_putline(v:count1 . ']p', 'Below')<CR>>']
n  >P          & :<C-U>call <SNR>52_putline(v:count1 . '[p', 'Above')<CR>>']
n  [C            9999[c
n  [c            <Plug>(signify-prev-hunk)
n  [xx           <Plug>unimpaired_line_xml_encode
n  [x            <Plug>unimpaired_xml_encode
n  [uu           <Plug>unimpaired_line_url_encode
n  [u            <Plug>unimpaired_url_encode
n  [yy           <Plug>unimpaired_line_string_encode
n  [y            <Plug>unimpaired_string_encode
n  [P            <Plug>unimpairedPutAbove
-- Plus --
```

Comment: This mapping is using `<LocalLeader>` so that would be what `:let maplocalleader` is set to, perhaps `\` which is the default? Does `\c` work here? Use `:nmap` to inspect the mappings that are set... Also double check that `:set ft?` confirms it's `ft=javascript`.

Comment: Note that vsplit opens a new window, not a buffer. If that buffer was already opened earlier and stays in memory (including being hidden due to `set hidden` and such) you won't get another `FileType` event just because you did a split.

Comment: It's working now!! Actually it has always been working, but I haven't seen it because it takes like a second or two to work, a bit weird.

Comment: @smarber If it takes a while to work, maybe it's because you have a separate mapping that uses `<localleader>c` as a prefix? So Vim is waiting to see if you're going to type more characters to trigger the longer mapping. Take a look at the output of `:nmap` to see if that's the case.

Comment: @filbranden this is my a part of `:nmap` https://ibb.co/CP9r6pc and this is how long it takes https://streamable.com/o70eb3

Comment: @smarber As a general advice, please [edit] your question to include more details, and try to avoid posting pictures of text when you could just copy & paste the text instead. By looking at your screenshot, I think I found the root of the issue you're having. I would stll appreciate it if you could edit your question to post those details there, in text format, so that the question and answer stands in a form that is useful for people that stumble upon it in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having happens because you have two mappings that conflict with each other, in that you have a second longer mapping that *starts* with `,c`, so when you type `,c` Vim doesn't know right away whether you want to invoke the commenting mapping (which is `,c`) or whether you are about to type the additional keys to invoke the longer mapping.

The image you posted with the output to `:nmap` shows the two mappings (although not next to each other):

```
n   ,c            *@I//<Esc>
n   ,cog          * call PhpCreateGetters()<CR>
```

In that case, and assuming that `'timeout'` is set (which is the default), then Vim will wait up to `'timeoutlen'` (defaults to one second) before it decides to execute the shorter mapping. See [`:help 'timeout'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27timeout%27) for more detail on these two settings.

To solve this issue, you can either disable or reconfigure the plug-in that is creating the longer mapping with the shared prefix (looks like a PHP language plug-in.) Reconfiguring that plug-in to use a different leader or prefix or a different mapping altogether for that particular feature would solve the problem.

Or you can pick a different key sequence for your comment mapping. For example, many plug-ins implementing commenting lines and blocks, such as [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) or [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) will use `gcc` (with no leader) to comment a single line, and other mappings starting with `gc` to comment other kinds of blocks. Perhaps picking the same key sequence would make sense here? (Or just adopt one of the plug-ins, if you're more interested in the commenting feature than in learning Vimscript.)